# The vpc none does not exist. - AWS CloudFormation

Tags: aws-cloudformation, rds

When I try to launch my AWS cloudformation stack in new region. Am getting error "The vpc none does not exist" when creating RDS service. Can anyone help me to fix this issue?

```
"dbsgdefault": {
    "Type": "AWS::RDS::DBSecurityGroup",
    "Properties": {
        "GroupDescription": "default"
    }
},
```

Comment: please provide stacktrace output or something simlar that shows problem description.

Comment: Be specific on your stacktrace and post the suspicious line.

Comment: 07:52:57 UTC+0550 CREATE_FAILED AWS::RDS::DBSecurityGroup dbsgdefault The vpc none does not exist.
Client Request Token:Console-CreateStack-491b4476-2d48-4af7-9d38-08eb4ce5a80c

Answer (score 2):

The [DBSecurityGroup documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-rds-security-group.html) suggests that `EC2VpcId` is required when creating a DBSecurityGroup in a VPC. It also suggests `DBSecurityGroupIngress` is required. Here is an example group using the two required fields:

```
 "DBSecurityGroup": {    
       "Type": "AWS::RDS::DBSecurityGroup",   
       "Properties": {
            "EC2VpcId" : { "Ref" : "VpcId" },
            "DBSecurityGroupIngress": [
                 {"EC2SecurityGroupName": { "Ref": "WebServerSecurityGroup"}}
            ],
            "GroupDescription": "Frontend Access"    
       } 
 }
```

If you are working outside of a VPC then you probably won't need `EC2VpcId` but you will definitely need a `DBSecurityGroupIngress` rule.

However, it does also say that DBSecurityGroup is not the recommended way to add security to DB instances and to use `VPCSecurityGroups` instead.

> The Id of the VPC. Indicates which VPC this DB Security Group should
>   belong to.
>
> **Important** The EC2VpcId property exists only for backwards
>   compatibility with older regions and is no longer recommended for
>   providing security information to an RDS DB instance. Instead, use
>   VPCSecurityGroups. Type: String
>
> *Required*: Conditional. Must be specified to create a DB Security Group
>   for a VPC; may not be specified otherwise.